# Django query expression for counting particular attendance

Tags: python, django, django-models, query-expressions

I have a field that has 1000 rows. In these rows there are 2 status available. Present and Absent. I want to know if there's a query expression to count the total number of students present or absent from the Attendence field so that i can store the answers in the respective fields (Attendance field has been populated with 'Present' and 'Absent').

```
class StudentInClass(models.Model):
    Attendance = models.CharField(max_length=20, default='None')
    Total_Present = models.IntegerField
    Total_Absent = models.IntegerField
```

I got it working with these commands but these are not what i exactly wanted. If there is an expression query for this then please let me know.

```
present_count = StudentInClass.objects.filter(Attendance__contains='Present').count 
absent_count = StudentInClass.objects.filter(Attendance__contains='Absent').count
```

Comment: Have a look at the [aggregation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/aggregation/#aggregation) section of the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you can use simple `group by`:

```
from django.db.models import Count

StudentInClass.objects.values('Attendance').annotate(count=Count('Attendance'))
```

Answer (score 0):

you are looking for filter methods. also I would have chosen BooleanField instead IntegerField. and then filter them and count.

```
class StudentInClass(models.Model):
    attendance = models.CharField(max_length=20, default='None')
    total_present = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    total_absent = models.BooleanField(default=False,null=True)

student_count = StudentIntClass.objects.filter(total_present==True).count()
```

similar to this.

Comment: I don't have a say in the field type as im working on data given from a csv, otherwise yes boolean would've been the ideal choice.

Answer (score 0):

Something like the below should work (not tested).

```
from django.db.models.aggregates import Sum
StudentInClass.objects.aggregate(sum_present=Sum("Total_Present"), sum_absent=Sum("Total_Absent"))
```

Comment: Hey I think you got the wrong idea. I just edit my question. Kindly re read.

Answer (score 0):

I got it work with these commands but these are not what i exactly wanted. If there is an expression query for this then please let me know.

present_count = StudentInClass.objects.filter(Attendance__contains='Present').count
absent_count = StudentInClass.objects.filter(Attendance__contains='Absent').count